# How to add items to system settings in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: settings

How can i add items such as unity tweak tool and CCSM and much more to system settings ? and i want them to open in the same windows instead of a new window when i click on them

Comment: Adding entries to the system settings menu should be possible, but it's not possible to run multiple applications inside the same window. Ergo, one need to change the source code of the system settings application to integrate the other applications.

Comment: And how can i do that?

Comment: The former (to add system menu entries) I don't know which is why I didn't write an answer. The latter (to integrate one application into another) requires skilful and laborious programming to port the functions and user interface of one application into another existing applications, i. e. nothing that fits within the scope of a Stack Exchange answer.